# In Python what is element of index?

Tags: python

```
import socket
try:
    url = input('Enter URL: ')
    host = url.split('/')[2]

    mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mysock.connect((host, 80))
    cmd = 'GET ' + host + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n'
    cmd = cmd.encode()
    mysock.send(cmd)
```

In the above code where it says:

```
host = url.split('/')[2]
```

I learnt from a video that to extract the host only it is element of index 2, but what actually is element of index?

Comment: Have you tried doing `print(url.split('/'))` (possibly preceded by `print(repr(url))`) to *see* what it's composed of? That will make the value of each index clearer.

Comment: in a list, each thing is an element, all of each have an index, a postition

Comment: I'm guessing the `url` in this case is expected to be in the form of `http://somedomain.com` in which case `url.split('/')` will return a list like `['http:','','somdomain.com']`. List indexes start at 0 and count up, so the item in that list with index `2` is `somedomain.com`.

Comment: Ideally, you should use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to get the host/authority or throw an error on an invalid URI, not rely on splitting random text

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what is happening in the program you attached.

```
url = input('Enter URL: ')
host = url.split('/')[2]
```

The first line in this program is gathering the user input.  Assume , you gave the following  input `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73640369/in-python-what-is-element-of-index` , the first part of  2nd line is splitting it using `/` as the separator.

so `url.split('/')` returns:

```
['https:', '', 'stackoverflow.com', 'questions', '73640369', 'in-python-what-is-element-of-index'].
```

This is a list and you are trying to get the 3rd index of that list by calling `[2]` . Note that in Python indices start from 0.

So finally , the variable `host` would contain `'stackoverflow.com'`

Comment: You unintentionally used '\' instead of '/'! But nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

An array contains some amount of elements. This example is an array of length `4`, which contains the elements `22`, `45`, `32` and `12`. As you can see, it starts counting at `0` and goes up to `index - 1`:

```
Index   0   1   2   3
Element 22  45  32  12
```

The method `split` returns an array of all the single strings in between your parameter ('/'). Example:

For `stackoverflow.com/questions/73640369/in-python-what-is-element-of-index`, it would return an array of length 4: `['stackoverflow.com', 'questions', '73640369', 'in-python-what-is-element-of-index']`.

Now you access the element at index `2`. Because you start counting at `0`, it is the 3rd element, in this case `73640369`.

So your code doesn't use all of the input, but only what is between the 2nd and 3rd (or end) slash.